# How can I find the maximum value of $\frac{y}{xy+2y+1} + \frac{z}{yz+2z+1} + \frac{x}{xz+2x+1}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, contest-math

$x$,$y$ and $z$ are positive real numbers.

We have to show that $$\frac{y}{xy+2y+1} + \frac{z}{yz+2z+1} + \frac{x}{xz+2x+1}\leq\frac{3}{4}.$$
I am the equivalent of a senior in high school  (not a US citizen) and we didn't take a multi-variable calculus course.
Is there a way this could be solved without it?

(It's a problem I found in a math olympiad somewhere,but I can't remember which one.)

Answer (score 1):

The full expanding gives:
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^2y^2z^2+2x^2y^2z-x^2yz+2x^2y-6xyz-xy+2x+1)\geq0,$$ which is true by AM-GM only:
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^2y^2z^2+1-2xyz)\geq0,$$
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^2y-xyz)\geq0,$$
$$1.5\sum_{cyc}(x^2y^2z+z-2xyz)\geq0,$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x^2z^2y+x^2y-2x^2yz)\geq0$$ and
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x^2y+y-2xy)\geq0.$$